# jQuery UI Datepicker not displaying year and month drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The jQuery UI date picker is not displaying the year and month drop-down. I am not using any custom CSS, just the jQuery UI CSS. Not sure what is causing this problem. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#id_dob").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          inst.dpDiv.css({
            marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px',
            marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'
          });
        },
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I was having same issue in my project and it was cause by different plugin code were overriding each other . You can check css [browser element tab]for that month div is there css which is overriding it .

Comment: More likely seems js or CSS issue. open your browser developer console and check for possible jquery errors or inspect the date picker and check CSS is not getting over-written by any other CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtdate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
            });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Date :
    <input id="txtdate" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```